# First response is slow Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I made a Java Web Application hosted by Tomcat. It can be found on this [URL](http://52.16.32.189/FIBIA_Autocomplete_v2/getData/?search=4760&getFiberStatus=false&prepopulateCity=true&zip=null).

The problem that I am experiencing is that whenever I visit the page the first time it takes about 10s while every time after it it takes only 100-500ms. I would say the speed improvement is due to browser caching, but not really, when I refresh cache too (`ctrl`+`shift`+`r`) I get the same quick response.

Then after some time, about 5 minutes I visit the page again and it's slow again.

You may try some tests yourself on the URL provided by changing the search parameter value to e.g.: `1050`,`1051`,`1052`,`2670`,`4000`,`2300`,`2200`.

Also the interesting fact I have spotted is that no matter how big payload (compare 1050 with 2300) the time is almost always the same approx. 9-10s. So what I assume is that something like Java Server has got to get ready and that is what is taking time.

**EDIT:**

I was first thinking it could be related to Java/Tomcat having to load some resources and then after some time +-3-5mins again because for some reason it unloaded it. But as I wrote above, even if I change the URL query string (that causes a different SQL query during execution), it again loads long. Can the issue be related to the DB? I am using MySQL.

**EDIT2:**

The reason why it's faster is most likely the server caching. I am 95% sure and that is because I made couple of experiments such as trying it on 2 computers etc. (no it's not browser caching). Then I realized that if it's fast only when it's cached, what takes so long is the actual `.executeQuery` line of code. It takes 10s even though the exact same request through a client such as `WorkBench` takes only 0.285s. Therefore I am going to try to use a `PreparedStatement` or experiment further.

Comment: Is your application hosted on a Tomcat instance, which serves multiple web applications (not just yours)? There's a possibility that Tomcat closes your app (to save Resources) when it's not used by anyone so it takes some time to reload when you next visit it.

Comment: Hmm yes there is one tomcat server and multiple apps on it. Is there a way to keep it open and ready for every app?

Comment: I don't know if you can keep it open but you can ask your web hosting provider. Maybe it's not the issue at all.

Comment: I am hosting it myself on AWS. Hmm it's shame I haven't got any answer on this or at least a guidance.

Comment: Try to debug it using your browser (press F12 and you see requests etc). This way you will know whether the browser is making some extra server trips when the page is taking long to load etc

Comment: No it's not the browser, it's that one single request that responds longer the first time.

Comment: Note  that while the cache-control attribute in the request header is set to no cache (in my browser), the response header cache-control attribute is set to 52 seconds, which basically instructs the browser to revalidate the same request after that period (same as hitting Refresh I think).

Answer (score 0):

The content is 200kB in size. You need to optimize it in the front and backend.

The main problem is in your backend. Check why it takes so long.

In the frontend you can enable gzip compression. Check the tomcat documentation on how to do it. This will reduce the size for the download.

The second time is probably faster for you due to browser caching.
Check the response code in Firebug, if the response is 304 it is cached. Response 200 means it has been loaded from the server.

Comment: As I said before, the second time it's fast and it's not due to browser caching. I tried an experiment where I made a request and then my colleague made a request on the same url and it was immediate. As I also mentioned the same 10s is even if it's small or a large payload, no matter. So no it's not the payload size. Though thanks for trying.

Comment: Use a profiler to analyze the bottleneck. There could be many different issues that could change the process time like jpa caching, memory usage, not properly configured db connection pool.....

Comment: It may be the server caching though.

Comment: The server should never cache your requests.

Comment: It apparently does or something must be happening if I visit a specific url, then I wait 10s till it loads then I send the same url to my colleague and he can see it right away. Then I send him a different url, he has to wait 10s and then I try to visit that one and it loads right away. Meaning it must be cached either on the server or something like DB connection stays open or something in that area.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? For me it has always taken 10 seconds.

Comment: No, no proxy. Even if you refresh the same page on the same url?

Answer (score 0):

ORM systems (like [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/orm/)) can cause significantly slow startup if you forget to turn off the initial modell-schema sync option in production environment, for example in [Spring](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) -> JPA -> Hibernate -> application-[server].yml->

```
spring:
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
```

<strike>update</strike> none

[If your model didn't change, switch "update" to "none" in the production environment for faster startup.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)